# changing MinSdk after launcing in Store for flutter App and error in install

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, release, android-min-sdk

I have launched a app  this 2 month ago with signing and this properties:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Now i added some new features like firebase messaging and firebase notification that require at least MinSdk 19 ;
So  i changed MinSdk to => 19 and change version from

```
version: 1.0.0+6
```

to

```
 version: 1.1.1+0
```

But when i release new version and try to update last version whit new version it make trouble whit error :

"Not Installed App : package appears to be corrupt"

(and i don't want to removing it from device because of logged users)
Could someone Help me about it?

Comment: As far as I understand in semantic versioning you can't have a build number 0.
so your version `1.1.1+0` is wrong try changing it to `1.1.1+1` let me know if it works

check this link too for more info 
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#version

Comment: Thanks dear friend it relieves me a lot that its not belong to Sdk thanks ;) it works

Answer (score 0):

Build number should be incremented every time you publish a new version to any app store. So it should be:

```
version: 1.1.1+7
```